# system.outofmemoryexception in StringBuilder

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

I have following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        strCsv.Append( XC.CleanForCsv(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][j].ToString()) + ",");
    }

    strCsv.Append( "\r\n" + strCsv)
}
```

`Dataset` contains  8000 records. Looping through the records using a `for` loop after only 15 records `strCsv.Append( "\r\n" + strCsv)` statement throws an exception saying `System.OutOfMemoryException`. What is the reason behind this exception?

Comment: Note for future questions - please pay more attention to formatting your code nicely. I'll edit the question now to show how it should have been posted to start with, but please do it on your initial post in future.

Answer (score 13):

Look at this:

```
strCsv.Append( "\r\n" + strCsv)
```

You're doubling the output on *every iteration*. That will build up *very* quickly - as well as giving you the wrong results.

I think you just want:

```
strCsv.Append("\r\n");
```